# How to realize the function of glEdgeFlag in openGL 3.1?

Tags: opengl

glEdgeFlag has been deprecated in OpenGL 3.1. What is it replaced with? If not replaced, how can I get a similar effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is replaced with nothing. If you want equivalent functionality, you will have to write it yourself using the available materials (ie: shader logic and vertex attributes), or find another way to do boundary checking for wireframe rendering.

Comment: think you for your reply.If I want to build the wireframe mesh from a given triangle mesh .can I realize it through add the edges I want to hilight as GL_LINES to an array,and then put it in a VBO?