# Multiple strip lines in one draw call

Tags: three.js, glsl, line, buffer-geometry

I want to draw a lot of strip lines and performance is very important to me so I can not use thousands of draw calls.

My first solution is using `LineSegments` with duplicate indexes like this

```
[1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,  1,7,7,6,6,8, ...]
```

I know about `BufferGeometry` and `ShaderMaterial` and instancing. Are those better than my solution?

Comment: Are all your lines connected to each other?

Comment: I have multi strip_lines I mean I have a lot of shape which any of them is a strip line and these shapes are not connect to each other

Comment: For performance, always prefer `BufferGeometry` over `Geometry`. Instancing won't help unless your lines are the same generalized shape, and transformable via `InstancedBufferAtributes` (probably a lot of data). Your current solution is probably your best bet to keep your draw calls down while minimizing your complexity and memory footprint.

Comment: so there is no way to make multi strip lines with one geometry?

Comment: see [How to realize the function of glEdgeFlag in openGL 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7227214/2521214) so in modern OpenGL the only option is geometry shader with use with indices with specific value meaning edge instead of vertex...

Comment: and we can not using geometry shader in webgl ?
so there is no chance?
Thansk a lot